# Run Go app created in windows in Docker container (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, go, docker, docker-container

I created very simple application that put to output some text.

My development environment is Windows + Docker for Windows. I created ubuntu container and after build my application in Windows for ubuntu

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOOS=linux
go build -o "myapp"
```

Then I copy 'myapp' file to shared folder and see it in shared folder of my container. 
After I try to run it inside container but there is an error

[image]

Why can't I run it? Was it built incorrectly or do I try to execute it in some wrong way?

In windows I have this output when I run my exe file and I want something the same in Ubuntu.

[image]

UPDATE
As suggested I try ./myapp and there is Exec format error

[image]

Comment: did you try ? `./myapp`

Comment: You wrote where you copy the result *to*, but not *from where* you take it. The build command uses another target directory than the install command.

Comment: I took the result from src/myProject folder after run build. New file appeared there and I copied it to container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ubuntu and other linux systems, just `myapp` will try to find `myapp` from the `PATH` environment variable. To look specifically for an executable inside the current directory, you need to use:

```
./myapp
```

Or use the complete path:

```
/__shared/myapp
```

UPDATE: for this to work, your file need to be executable. You can verify it using `ls -l`:

```
ls -l
-rwxrwxr-x  1 user user    0 Feb  9 09:45 myapp
```

If you don't see at least one 'x' in the first column, you need to run:

```
chmod +x myapp
```

See [understanding-linux-file-permissions](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions) for more information on the subject.

UPDATE: the error `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error'` could come from:

- a mismatch between the system architecture and the file --> ensure your ubuntu machine is a 64-bit version and compare the output of `uname -a` and `file myapp`
- according to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/697757/503320), running a file inside the shared folder of the VM (with windows host) can cause trouble --> try to copy myapp outside the shared folder

Comment: It's better, after I call as you said I have './myapp: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error' :) 
So there is another problem

Comment: updated the answer, tell me if this resolves your problem.

Comment: It seems that it is executable. 

>> root@7dd1655ae5db:/__shared# ls -l
>> total 1764
>> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1804288 Feb  9  2017 myapp

Comment: Simple test showed that it is not the shared folder problem :) I try to run 'file myapp' command and see that 'bash: file: command not found'. Could you tell me if I need to install something to use this command or maybe there is some other one :) Anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: bash in usually under `/bin/bash`. try `echo $PATH`. If it is empty, use `export PATH=/bin/bash` and try again. For this kind of problem, I suggest searching on google first and maybe post another question if you can't figure it out by yourself. Can we consider this question answered ?